# Typescript multiple types in one dynamic type issue with map function

Tags: typescript, dictionary, dynamic, types, interface

I wanted to use similar but different types under same 'dynamic' type, so I made:

```
export type ICandidate = 
  | ICandidatePlain
  | ICandidateTalented
  | ICandidateExperienced
```

the reason behind it is because objects in candidates array can have different properties from each other

that `ICandidate` type worked fine as candidates were just part of the object:

```
export interface Process {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  candidates: ICandidate[]
}
```

the issue was revealed later as I have need to map all candidates to their specific component(which depends on type).

[here is a link to codesandbox, error on line #14](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-type-issue-s56qh?file=/src/App.tsx)

Is there some other way I can make this work?

I am guessing that map expects array of objects with completely same properties - or either type from type `ICandidate` but not mixed, how can I make it to work with mixed types inside single array?

Current workaround is putting any for type `data.map((candidate: any)=>{...}` but I want to make it right with proper typing, not just hacking around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `exampleObject.ts` you have:

```
//...
data: [
    {
      type: "plain",
      //...
    },
    {
      type: "talented",
      //...
    },
    {
      type: "experienced"
      //...
    }
  ]
...
```

The problem with that is that typescript will widen the type of `type` to `string` (instead of `"plain" | "talented" | "experienced"`) by default and it will fail to detect your discrimator field. You have to either declare separate variable with annotation:

```
const data : ICandidate[] = [...];
```

or add `as const` everywhere to tell typescript not to widen the type:

```
data: [
    {
      type: "plain" as const,
      //...
    },
    {
      type: "talented" as const,
      //...
    },
    {
      type: "experienced" as const,
      //...
    }
  ]
```

Comment: The second part of solution is perfect for my use case! It worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for this answer and explanation on how it works under the hood!